# How to recover data when the SSD read test failed

Tags: linux, ssd, data-recovery, thinkpad

Unfortunately, the SSD device on my Notebook LENOVO ThinkPad T590 has a reading failure. When running diagnostic at the Boot Menu, the SSD read test failed (see image below). The laptop is unable to load the OS (Ubuntu) and has no response.

I was wondering if there is an option of running a light version of Linux on a USB stick and then use some software that can access the SSD drive and attempt some data recovery. Or something similar.

[image]

Comment: Use any Live Linux system and the `dd_rescue`.

Comment: I'd have thought if the entire NVMe and device read has failed, there'd be nothing to copy. I'd say it's time to replace the drive & recover from your backup; or get the drive out & see if it's the bus that's failed rather than the drive itself.

Comment: @Robert, thanks for the suggestion. I used a Live Linux system on a USB stick and I could read a lot of data from the SSD without any special tool. Not sure then why the reading test failed. So, thanks to the gods of the binary system, I recovered what I needed :)